# KeyVault firewall configuration and Azure Functions consumption plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-app-service-plans

I have a KeyVault with some secrets in it. I have configured the firewall with a few limited client IPs and also made sure the "Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this firewall" is set to "Yes".

However, when I try connect and retrieve a secret from an Azure function (using Managed Service Identity) I get a 403, Forbidden. If I set the firewall off (i.e. to "Allow access from all networks") then it works fine.

In the (i)nformation box it says that Azure App Services (Web Apps) are supported. I thought this would cover function apps too but obviously not.

I know that I can use a S1 plan and a VNET (and join KeyVault to the same VNET), but then we lose the flexibility of the consumption plan.

I have considered adding the entire Azure IP range for the data centre in question but I don't want the admin overhead.

Any other thoughts on how to secure a KeyVault using a firewall but still be able to access it from a function running on a consumption plan?

[image: Supported internal services]

Answer (score 2):

Go to your function properties (function > platform features > properties ) and look up ip addresses there (they do not change) and add those to the KV firewall.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately those IP addresses may change (infrequently) which makes them unreliable for production deployment. See https://twitter.com/jussipalo/status/985781858020610049

Comment: i've been using those throughout the last several years in different places. never seen them change.

Comment: They may change, but Azure will notify you about it in advance.

Comment: Thanks @PawelMaga - can you point me to any documentation that confirms this?

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft Unfortunately I don't have any link to the documentation confirming it. I can just copy/paste a few words from email message that I got from Azure many times: "To improve traffic flow, we are changing some of the inbound and outbound IP addresses in regions where your sites are hosted. We’re making these changes over the next few months and require you to take corresponding actions. If you don’t take the recommended action described below by September 30, 2018, your site may stop working."

Comment: Anyone find anything out about this in the past 2 years?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone comes by this as I did, here is the current documentation (Aug 2023) recommendation concerning Functions accessing Key Vault.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=portal

> For some platform-level features such as Key Vault references, the origin IP might not be one of the outbound IPs, and you should not configure the target resource to rely on these specific addresses. It is recommended that the app instead use a virtual network integration, as the platform will route traffic to the target resource through that network.